# Possible to injure someone when penalties are switched off?

Tags: ios, fifa-12

I've noticed in many modern soccer/football games if you turn off penalties then injuries are also disabled. Essentially preventing people from having fun and beating the other team through injury.

Supplementary question; is this done deliberately? That is, has a game company ever come out and said we can't have this feature because sponsors or FIFA or license holders etc. won't allow it?

Main question; it appears it is possible in FIFA 12 because there are two separate settings for penalties and injuries. However I have just played two 6 minute games and couldn't manage to get anyone sent off due to injury. However if I set both settings to ON then it is quite easy (even if it costs me a couple of red cards) to at least get one person sent off injured. So is this possible in FIFA 12 on iOS?

I remember in early PS2 versions of [ISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Superstar_Soccer) that it could be done, but I can't remember if that had official teams and players.

Comment: I remember this wasn't possible even back in fifa 98, though its been a long time since I played a fifa game.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I think you should make clearer what your question is. What do penalties have to do with injuries? And in the middle part you say it's quite easy when you adjust the settings and then you ask if it's possible?

Answer (score 2):

Ok first of all yes it is possible, but it does take a fair bit of practice to perfect it.

The best way to injure someone is while you are running alongside your opponent, let them move ahead of you just a little bit and then try a slide tackle. If you time this correctly it should work